# How to replace lowest value in each column as na value

Tags: r

I am working on a metabolomics dataset in R.

I need help with two things:
1) Replace each NA values in a specific column (compound/metabolite)  with the lowest meassured value for the metabolite (in the same column).

2) Find the median value for each column(compound/metabolite) and then divide each of the observation in the same column by this value. We only want the median value of the controls [7:10,](row 7 to 10), but ultimatley divide the meassured value by of all observations in the column, both healthy controls and diseased by this value.

I have put a small sample of my dataset[1:10,1:10] here, so you get an idea of what I am working with:

```
DF = structure(c(1860651, 1337891, 2798250, 3346226, 1573569, 1617225, 
2165432, 1810660, 2959953, 1646724, 131017, 84179, NA, 319922, 
146119, 144214, 293748, 115225, 91870, 251489, 151948, 45234, 
NA, 272300, 148625, 148467, 281923, 104149, 73209, 309631, 503723, 
335152, 204554, 1085158, 402338, 573637, 1326537, 476902, 320715, 
1054230, 73001, NA, NA, 134919, 41893, 60296, 172660, 46089, 
NA, 113501), .Dim = c(10L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(c("M_1", "M_2", 
"M_3", "M_4", "M_5", "M_6", "M_7", "M_8", "M_9", "M_10"), c("(N(1) + N(8))-acetylspermidine", 
"1-carboxyethylisoleucine", "1-carboxyethylleucine", "1-carboxyethylphenylalanine", 
"1-carboxyethyltyrosine")))
```

Thank you in advance for you help :)

Comment: Did this make sense?

Comment: There should only be one question per question on SO.

Comment: Also, replacing NA's with minima seems a potentially dubious thing to do.  If the NAs are there because you were below detection limit, then they should be treated as not-detected, rather than artificially increased to the minimum

Comment: Hey, this is a convention used in metabolomics - however I agree with you. Its wierd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this accomplish what you want?

```
temp <- DF
temp[is.na(temp)] <- 0
newDF <- temp + is.na(DF)*apply(DF,2,min, na.rm=T)
apply(newDF,2,function(x) {x/median(x[7:10])})
```

Here is the output after running this

```
          (N(1) + N(8))-acetylspermidine 1-carboxyethylisoleucine 1-carboxyethylleucine 1-carboxyethylphenylalanine 1-carboxyethyltyrosine
M_1                       0.9359195                0.7145459             0.7871485                   0.6579746              0.5102093
M_2                       0.6729678                0.4590989             0.2343293                   0.4377833              0.5883331
M_3                       1.4075379                0.2466991             0.2343293                   0.2671932              0.3161437
M_4                       1.6831733                1.7448039             1.4106177                   1.4174585              0.9429587
M_5                       0.7915154                0.7969099             0.7699341                   0.5255432              0.2927932
M_6                       0.8134746                0.7865203             0.7691156                   0.7492979              0.4214131
M_7                       1.0892263                1.6020550             1.4604685                   1.7327533              1.2067333
M_8                       0.9107737                0.6284189             0.5395315                   0.6229404              0.3221194
M_9                       1.4888755                0.5010444             0.3792505                   0.4189253              1.4296428
M_10                      0.8283128                1.3715811             1.6040065                   1.3770596              0.7932667
```

Comment: Hey, this worked great! However, could you help us to just select the median for controls?

Comment: The above currently only calculates the median value from the observations in rows 7 to 10. Are these the controls?

Comment: Hey. Yes these are controls

Comment: Awesome, no problem!